# How can I place input fields into react-admin's list view?

Tags: react-admin

When I try to use an input component in a list view like I would in an edit view, it throws an error:

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'control')

How can I fix the error and use any kind of input in the list view?

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to use InputField in a Show?

If you want to display a resource property you should use [React Admin TextField](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/TextField.html#usage) instead. Anyway, if the requirements need an input in a ShowView, you can use MUI's [TextField](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/) and create a custom behavior.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).